# When developing a website with visual studio, how do I improve the build time?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, build

I have a lot of classes in the App_Code directory could this be a problem? Would it build faster if it was in a separate library?

Any other tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a decent article [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bradleyb/archive/2005/12/06/432441.aspx). Items listed there are:

- Do not disable batch compilation
- Leverage Server-side Compilation
- Move App_Code files into a separate class library project
- Check for conflicting dependencies
- Turn off AutoToolboxPopulate in the Windows Forms Designer options.
- Disable validation for HTML editing

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a second project, let's say "MyLibrary", instead of having a bloated App_Code folder.